# Any way to shows specific List view in the Community?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, list-view

I don't have ideas how to realize it. But I have to show the specific List View on the custom object in the Community.
There is any way to create a component? Or maybe I can do this by setting up on the Org?

FYI: I have a custom object, and I have a custom list view on it. How can i show ONLY this list view in the Community, so no one will have the opportunity to choose another list view

Answer (score 1):

Once you click on edit of the list view, you need to select **Visible to certain groups of users** and select **All Partner Users** (which means only community users and see it).
And similarly **All Internal Users** for only within the Org visibility.

[image: List View Restriction to only Community Users]

Thanks
Amrut

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the permissions on the other list views so that they are not visible by community users.